# amcharts 4, tooltip individual para cada dato

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Estoy revisando y no puedo encontrar la solución a mi problema. Estoy usando amcharts 4. Necesito añadir tooltip individual para cada dato porque en algunos puntos de la serie "Horizonte 2030" tiene que mostrar un texto diferente, en ve del general para todos los elementos.

¿Podría alguien ayudarme, por favor?

Por más que busco o hago modificaciones no consigo solucionarlo. Sé que debería aladir alguna variable toooltip para Horizonte2030 dentro de cada elemento de los 10 que lo conforman y luego invocarlo pero no soy capaz ni encuentro como hacerlo.

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "year": "2012",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 7.49,
  "value3": 18.21
}, {
  "year": "2013",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 6.85,
  "value3": 15.48
}, {
  "year": "2014",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 7.26,
  "value3": 16.95
}, {
  "year": "2015",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 8.24,
  "value3": 19.22
}, {
  "year": "2016",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 8.48,
  "value3": 19.22
}, {
  "year": "2017",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 9.28,
  "value3": 20.08
}, {
  "year": "2018",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 9.28,
  "value3": 20.08
}, {
  "year": "2019",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 9.66,
  "value3": 21.29
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "horizonte": 25,
  "value2": 9.98,
  "value3": 22.01
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "horizonte": 25,
   "value2": 10.79,
  "value3": 27.45
}];

// Create category axis
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

valueAxis.title.text = "[bold]Sup. ECO / SAU (%)[/]";
valueAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;

// Create series
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "horizonte";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series1.name = "Horizonte 2030";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "Place taken by {name} in {categoryX}: {valueY}";
series1.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";
series1.visible  = false;


var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "value2";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series2.name = 'España';
series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series2.tooltipText = "{name} : {valueY}%";
series2.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "value3";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series3.name = 'Andalucía';
series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series3.tooltipText = "Place taken by {name} in {categoryX}: {valueY}";
series3.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";

// Add chart cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";


let hs1 = series1.segments.template.states.create("hover")
hs1.properties.strokeWidth = 5;
series1.segments.template.strokeWidth = 1;

let hs2 = series2.segments.template.states.create("hover")
hs2.properties.strokeWidth = 5;
series2.segments.template.strokeWidth = 1;

let hs3 = series3.segments.template.states.create("hover")
hs3.properties.strokeWidth = 5;
series3.segments.template.strokeWidth = 1;

// Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("over", function(event){
  var segments = event.target.dataItem.dataContext.segments;
  segments.each(function(segment){
    segment.isHover = true;
  })
})

chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("out", function(event){
  var segments = event.target.dataItem.dataContext.segments;
  segments.each(function(segment){
    segment.isHover = false;
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```